# Why I got crash when allocating buffer?

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, driver

I am developing a driver with Filter. So when I write the `SendNetBufferListsComplete` function in `filter.cpp` I got a crash (bluescreen). WinDbug pointed to some buffer allocation. The code is here:

**Edited:**

```
sendNetBufferListsComplete(
    IN PNET_BUFFER_LIST NetBufferLists,
    IN ULONG SendCompleteFlags) {

    PNET_BUFFER_LIST pNetBufferList = NetBufferLists;
    PNET_BUFFER_LIST pNextNetBufferList = NULL;

    while (pNetBufferList) 
    {
        pNextNetBufferList = NET_BUFFER_LIST_NEXT_NBL(pNetBufferList);
        NET_BUFFER_LIST_NEXT_NBL(pNetBufferList) = NULL;
        PNET_BUFFER_LIST pParentNetBufferList = pNetBufferList->ParentNetBufferList;

        if (pParentNetBufferList != NULL)
        {
            NDIS_STATUS status = NET_BUFFER_LIST_STATUS(pNetBufferList);
            NdisFreeNetBufferList(pNetBufferList);

            if (NdisInterlockedDecrement(&pParentNetBufferList->ChildRefCount) == 0) {
                NET_BUFFER_LIST_STATUS(pParentNetBufferList) = status;
                NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete(m_hFilter, pParentNetBufferList, SendCompleteFlags);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(pNetBufferList != NULL) 
            {
                **---windbug pointed here---****

                PVOID pBuffer = *(PVOID*) NET_BUFFER_LIST_CONTEXT_DATA_START(pNetBufferList);

                PMDL pMdl = NET_BUFFER_FIRST_MDL(NET_BUFFER_LIST_FIRST_NB(pNetBufferList));

                if(pMdl)
                    NdisFreeMdl(pMdl);

                if(pBuffer)
                    delete[] (UCHAR*) pBuffer;

                NdisFreeNetBufferList(pNetBufferList);                
            }
        }

        NdisInterlockedDecrement(&m_nSendNetBufferListCount);
        pNetBufferList = pNextNetBufferList;
    }
```

What is the actual problem? Is it overflow? Or NULL check problems?

In `ndish.h`

```
#define NET_BUFFER_LIST_CONTEXT_DATA_START(_NBL)    ((PUCHAR)(((_NBL)->Context)+1)+(_NBL)->Context->Offset)
```

like this . and in Wdm.h

```
//
// I/O system definitions.
//
// Define a Memory Descriptor List (MDL)
//
// An MDL describes pages in a virtual buffer in terms of physical pages.  The
// pages associated with the buffer are described in an array that is allocated
// just after the MDL header structure itself.
//
typedef
    _Struct_size_bytes_(_Inexpressible_(sizeof(struct _MDL) +    // 747934
       (ByteOffset + ByteCount + PAGE_SIZE-1) / PAGE_SIZE * sizeof(PFN_NUMBER)))
  struct _MDL {
    struct _MDL *Next;
    CSHORT Size;
    CSHORT MdlFlags;

    struct _EPROCESS *Process;
    PVOID MappedSystemVa;   /* see creators for field size annotations. */
    PVOID StartVa;   /* see creators for validity; could be address 0.  */
    ULONG ByteCount;
    ULONG ByteOffset;
} MDL, *PMDL;
```

Comment: Most likely, you have a non-null but invalid pointer. You never modify `pNetBufferList`, so it's unclear how the loop is supposed to end. (Note that an optimiser may remove `if(pNetBufferList != NULL) ` since you've already dereferenced `pNetBufferList`.) Also, are you sure that `pBuffer` was allocated with `new[]`?

Comment: where i dereferenced `pNetBufferList` ? The loop will end when the `pNetBufferList = NULL` . and i missed the code in the end of while like `pNetBufferList = pNextNetBufferList;`

Comment: i edited added some lines of code before going to while loop agin . sorry . my mistake . Then why this crash occur ?

Comment: The first three lines in the loop all dereference `pNetBufferList`. You also know that it's not null - the loop is still looping - so the test is pointless. *Something* has made the context pointer go bad, but it's impossible to guess what.

Comment: is it correct    `PVOID pBuffer = *(PVOID*) NET_BUFFER_LIST_CONTEXT_DATA_START(pNetBufferList);`  ?  and after that `delete[] (UCHAR*) pBuffer;`  the casting and deleting with `UCHAR*` cause any problems ? or any buffer overflow ?

Comment: If you put a pointer to a memory block allocated with `new[]` there it should be correct, otherwise it shouldn't. If it should be correct and isn't, you've broken the data somewhere else.